# Getting only the value of a particular node in XML from PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have this.xml file with content:

```
<Parameters>   
<Parameter IsEncrypted="False">
        <ParameterName>pTxtAppPoolNameRefbiq</ParameterName>
        <ParameterValue>MESDataAccess4.0</ParameterValue>   
</Parameter>   
<Parameter IsEncrypted="False">
        <ParameterName>pTxtFoldrSouceMediaLoc_OPCDA</ParameterName>
        <ParameterValue>C:\</ParameterValue>   
</Parameter> 
</Parameters>
```

Now, I want to get the ParameterValue ("C:\") of ParameterName = pTxtFoldrSouceMediaLoc_OPCDA.

As of now i have only tried:

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content this.xml);
$xml.Parameters.Parameter | Where-Object {$_.ParameterName -eq pTxtFoldrSouceMediaLoc_OPCDA} | Select-Object ParameterValue;
```

But i am getting output as:

```
ParameterValue                                                                                           
--------------                                                                                           
C:\
```

What I require is just the value `"C:\"` as output in PowerShell.
How do I write a PowerShell script so as to fetch only that particular node value?

Thank you for checking in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
($xml.Parameters.Parameter | Where-Object {$_.ParameterName -eq "pTxtFoldrSouceMediaLoc_OPCDA"}).ParameterValue
```